# WiX component source in GAC

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

It is trivial to install a component to GAC by using WiX. However, I want exactly opposite. I have some components in GAC on a computer where I build WiX project. I want to make GAC a source for some of my components instead of tricky process of manually extracting them from GAC and storing in a specific folder to give WiX an explicit file path. Is it possible to instruct WiX to take components for setup directly from GAC without supplying full machine specific path to it?

Comment: Yes. This is the duplicate to another question pointed. Sorry missing it before. Thank you.

Comment: Especially, the second answer there with a hint for using 'copy local' attribute in project is very useful.